# SharePoint SPService SPCascade dropdown show none in the edit mode

Tags: spservices

We have 2 relationship lists such as Category and Sub Category List
We successfully set cascade behaviour in the new item page.

```
$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
       relationshipList: "relatLv0ToLv1",
       relationshipListParentColumn: "Parent",
       relationshipListChildColumn: "Child",
       parentColumn: "CategoryLvl0",
       childColumn: "CategoryLvl1",
   });
```

After save, the information displays correctly.
However, when we tried to edit item, the child category always show none instead of its value

[image]

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Regards

Comment: I use Sparqube lookup columns, by default they do not allow edit in the DATASHEET view.  This can be changed in the column settings though.  From your question it is not clear if you are using a Datasheet view or simply trying to edit the item (Edit Form).

Comment: have you added the same code to cascade dropdowns on both new and edit form?

Comment: Yes, I added the same snippet in the new and edit form. Actually, in the edit form, the value in the dropdown is filtered but it just display (none).

Comment: Is that the only function/piece of code you have in your forms?

Comment: Actually, there is two line for importing the jquery and spservice and then this piece of code. This is the same script that we use for both newForm and editForm. The newForm work correctly. But the editForm could not select the store value and display none. I suspect that the event was fire so then the cascade is loading to none.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the root cause. The problem occurs if we use the lookup column fields as parent. If we change the parent field from lookup to simple text, it's working fine.

Best Regards,

Andy